# Извлечь определенные данные в тексте

Tags: python

Есть определенная строка; формат строки везде одинаковый, но длина разная - пример:

```
['1.3', '1854', '1.4.1.0', '6.3.1.1', '47480.3.2.2.4.0', '1']
```

или

```
['1.3', '1854', 1.3.1.1', '1.4.1.0', '6.3.1.1', '480.1.2.2.0.0', '1']
```

и т. д.

Надо извлечь только предпоследние данные в строке без кавычек.
Должно получится так: `а = 47480.3.2.2.4.0`
или  `а = 480.1.2.2.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

Непонятно, зачем тут вообще регулярные выражения. Предпоследний элемент берется вот так:

```
a = s[-2]
```

Кавычки означают, что это строка, и частью данных не являются.